# HTML <select> tag issue on android tablet

Tags: android, css, html, tablet

While making the site responsive, I remarked that select tag isn't working properly on android tablet browser (it's working on chrome browser of that tablet). Particularly I don't manage to give to this tag the height that I want, and when I add border or border-radius, the select arrow disappears. Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            select {
                font-size: 15px;
                height: 40px;
                width: 200px;
                padding: 6px;
                border-radius: 6px;
                border: 1px solid #666666;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone suggest how to make select formalization properly for android tablet?

You may see the select here

http://www.inants.com/kadmos/web/select.html

On my tablet it's android 4.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which browser on the tablet ISN'T it working?

Comment: Android default browser

Comment: So Chrome?...but you said it was working in Chrome....is that not the default browser? If not, what is the name of the browser?

Comment: Its name is Browser, I don't know if it has other name or not, it's Android Browser!

Comment: There is no such thing (AFAIK) as "Android Browser"....it was probably installed by the tablet manufacturer so you would have to find out what engine it's based on. Of course, styling browser /OS objects like a `select` is usually best left to the browser. Styling it carries, as you have discovered, it's own risk.